# REST API design for keyword based query

Tags: spring-boot, rest, backend

I am trying to architect a REST API design to give the best results to users based on keywords. User will have the option to select keywords (Like 'new', 'top rated', 'open now') and the REST API shall return the best result sets based on the selected keyword.

This is somewhat similar to how Google Maps is implemented. (See the image in the link below for reference) - User can select 'Open now' and 'Top rated', and Google shows the top rated stores that are open.

https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleMaps/comments/j07cf1/does_anyone_else_find_the_google_maps_search/

I am using Spring as our backend framework and I am lost and not sure where to start. I believe the SQL query should be constructed based on selected user keywords but not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Can anyone familiar with this subject share some ideas on this?

Comment: Have you design your database schema?

Answer (score 0):

you could use spring boot backed micro services to perform this. you may want to have an api business services (REST endpoint) that interacts with your client and then a core service (REST endpoint) to interact with your DB

Answer (score 0):

You can take the benefit of framework like graphql etc.